# About categories in drupal classified website

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Hi i have a dobt i am making a classified website and i have this problem with the ads categories when i put a contextual filter because i want to show a page with the categories and the number of ads in that category

example: Mobile Phone Services (3)

the problem is that this contextual filter is only showing me the categories where i have some ads and it does not show me the categories where i dont have ads yet, what  am i doing wrong? there is a way through this contextual filter to show even the categories that i dont have any ads yet

example: I want that

Mobile Phone Services (3)
Mobile Phones (0)
Car Kit and Handsfree (0)

See now is only showing me Mobile Phone Services because i have 3 ads in this categories and i want to show all categories even with no ads, please someone could help me, I would appreciate it a lot, i am working in localhost with wampserver, and drupal 7 and no using taxonomies i wish i could do this with views and contextual filters if someone understand my situation please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've created a view of nodes grouped by terms.  I think what you want is a view of terms with their associated nodes pulled in by a relationship, and grouped by term.  Then you'll get all terms.

Create a new view.  On the create view page, change "Show: Content" to "Show: Taxonomy terms".  Change "of type: All" to a specific vocabulary if you wish to restrict it.  Add your page settings.  Click Continue & Edit.

Now, under "Advanced", add a relationship of type "Taxonomy term: Content with term".  Leave "require this relationship" unchecked.

Add a field to your view of type "Content: Title", that uses the relationship you just created.  Remove it's label.  This brings in the node titles of the associated nodes.

Under "Format", then "settings" in the first column of your view, change "Grouping Field" to "Taxonomy Term: name".  You should now see term headings with nodes and terms under each one.

Edit the existing "Taxonomy term: name" field and check "Exclude from display".  This removes the duplicate term display.

Now add two sorts, first by "Taxonomy term: name", then by "Content: title".

Hope that helps...

Comment: if someone could be a little more specific in this answer i ll appreciate it a lot thanks.